# Amount of balance increases randomly and decreases

Tags: java, android

I'm learning making simple dice application, But I've just encountered problem.
The problem is when I pressed the Lowbtn and Highbtn It just increase and decrease
randomly regardless of If statement.
If my thought was right When pressed Highbtn and number result is higher than multiplier,
Then It should only increase its balance amount by 0.1 .I used if statements instead of switch
 because I'm beginner.

Below is my code :

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class FieldActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".########");
    Button Highbtn, Lowbtn;
    EditText BetAmount, Multiplier;
    TextView Balance;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_field);
        Highbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Highbtn);
        Lowbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LowBtn);
        BetAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BetAmount);
        Multiplier = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Multiplier);
        Balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Balance);
        String userData = Balance.getText().toString();
        float balance1 = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", Float.parseFloat(userData));
        Balance.setText(String.format("%f", balance1));
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Highbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userData = Balance.getText().toString();
                float balance1 = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", Float.parseFloat(userData));
                float betamount1 = 0;
                float multiplier = Float.valueOf(Multiplier.getText().toString());
                try {
                    multiplier = Float.valueOf(Multiplier.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (balance1 >= betamount1) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                    editor.apply();
                    double number = Math.random() * 100;
                    TextView Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);
                    String Number1 = df1.format(number);
                    String Balance1 = df2.format(balance1);
                    Number.setText(Number1);
                    Balance.setText(Balance1);
                    if (multiplier <= number) {
                        balance1 += 0.10000000;
                        editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                        editor.apply();
                    } else if(multiplier >= number) {
                        balance1 -= 0.10000000;
                        editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
                if (balance1 <= 0.00000000) {
                    balance1 += 1.00000000;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                    editor.apply();
                    Balance.setText(String.format("%f", balance1));
                    String Balance1 = df2.format(balance1);
                    Balance.setText(Balance1);
                }
                if (balance1 < betamount1) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                    editor.apply();
                    Balance.setText(String.format("%f", balance1));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insufficient Funds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        Lowbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userData = Balance.getText().toString();
                float balance1 = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", Float.parseFloat(userData));
                float betamount1 = 0;
                float multiplier = Float.valueOf(Multiplier.getText().toString());;
                try{
                    multiplier = Float.valueOf(Multiplier.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (balance1 >= betamount1) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                    editor.apply();
                    double number = Math.random() * 100;
                    TextView Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);
                    String Number1 = df1.format(number);
                    String Balance1  = df2.format(balance1);
                    Number.setText(Number1);
                    Balance.setText(Balance1);
                    if(multiplier >= number){
                        balance1 += 0.10000000;
                        editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                    else if(multiplier <= number){
                        balance1 -= 0.10000000;
                        editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
                if (balance1 <= 0.00000000) {
                    balance1 += 1.00000000;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                    editor.apply();
                    Balance.setText(String.format("%f", balance1));
                    String Balance1  = df2.format(balance1);
                    Balance.setText(Balance1);
                }
                if (balance1 < betamount1) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", balance1);
                    editor.apply();
                    Balance.setText(String.format("%f", balance1));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insufficient Fund", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Why have you did `float balance1 = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("FLOAT_KEY1", Float.parseFloat(userData));` this twice? Declare the variables as public once.

Comment: now I did, but I get NullPointerException Error. What should I do?

Comment: Move all declarations to outside your onCreate like public float balance1,String userData etc. NullPointerException is because of issue in proper initialization. Check that

Comment: also add your crash log